# Debugging Issue: After Updating Emacs Input Lags Massively

Tags: debugging, performance

After updating Emacs, I am seeing incredibly lagging input performance. I thought the slowness was due to LSP, but it seems to persist even when I disable LSP-mode. Unless I disable all major and minor modes, the input lag can cause things to hang for multiple seconds. The lag is more noticeable if I "type quickly" or cause a number of inputs in a short amount of time.

This is the profile I collected using the CPU profiler:

```
   Samples  %   Function
   40184  41% + timer-event-handler
   20909  21% + redisplay_internal (C function)
   17718  18% + command-execute
    5234   5% + company-post-command
    4299   4% + #<compiled 0x15e5c2a54bebe16d>
    1950   2% + ...
    1691   1% + lsp-ui-doc--make-request
    1498   1% + term-emulate-terminal
    1323   1% + flycheck-handle-signal
    1253   1% + flyspell-post-command-hook
     390   0% + jit-lock--antiblink-post-command
     275   0% + server-process-filter
     105   0% + undo-auto--add-boundary
      73   0% + eldoc-pre-command-refresh-echo-area
      72   0% + lsp-ui-sideline
      58   0% + flycheck-perform-deferred-syntax-check
      58   0% + sml/generate-position-help
      50   0% + flycheck-maybe-display-error-at-point-soon
      46   0% + lsp--post-command
      34   0% + yas--post-command-handler
      34   0% + company-pre-command
      31   0% + gui-set-selection
      16   0% + internal-default-process-filter
      15   0% + magit-section-update-highlight
      12   0%   internal-timer-start-idle
       7   0% + #<compiled -0xa5d682cf5d3f799>
       4   0% + eldoc-schedule-timer
       3   0%   clear-minibuffer-message
       3   0% + internal-echo-keystrokes-prefix
       2   0%   tooltip-hide
       2   0% + #<compiled 0x189287ae925f6744>
       2   0% + blink-cursor-end
       1   0% + transient--pre-command
```

Expanding the `timer-event-handler` it seems that `auto-revert-buffers` is taking up a lot of cycles, but I don't know if that's abnormal or not:

```
   Samples  %   Function
   40184  41% - timer-event-handler
   40108  41%  - apply
   23800  24%   - auto-revert-buffers
   23800  24%    - apply
   23786  24%     - auto-revert-buffers--buffer-list-filter
   23761  24%      - #<subr auto-revert-buffers>
   12720  13%       - auto-revert--buffer-candidates
    1605   1%          #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_26>
    1136   1%          auto-revert--polled-buffers
    6251   6%       - auto-revert-buffer
    6186   6%        - auto-revert-handler
    3596   3%           dired-buffer-stale-p
     370   0%         - revert-buffer
     370   0%          - dired-revert
     193   0%           - dired-readin
     171   0%            - combine-change-calls-1
     170   0%             - #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_37>
     166   0%              - dired-readin-insert
     154   0%               - dired-insert-directory
     132   0%                - insert-directory
     132   0%                 - apply
     132   0%                  - ls-lisp--insert-directory
     118   0%                     #<subr insert-directory>
       5   0%                  dired-insert-set-properties
       4   0%                - dired--insert-disk-space
       1   0%                 - get-free-disk-space
       1   0%                    file-size-human-readable-iec
       3   0%                  dired-switches-escape-p
      19   0%            - dired--make-directory-clickable
      16   0%             - define-keymap
      16   0%              - keymap-set
      11   0%               - keymap--check
      11   0%                - key-valid-p
       4   0%                   #<compiled 0xb4e51d99dc37b>
       1   0%               - key-parse
       1   0%                  #<compiled 0xb4e51d99dc37b>
       1   0%               jit-lock-after-change
      90   0%           - hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer
      90   0%            - hack-dir-local-variables
      90   0%             - hack-dir-local--get-variables
      90   0%              - dir-locals-find-file
      82   0%                 locate-dominating-file
      69   0%           - dired-restore-positions
      49   0%            - dired-goto-file
       4   0%               file-relative-name
       2   0%             - dired-goto-file-1
       2   0%                dired-switches-escape-p
       9   0%           - dired-save-positions
       9   0%            - walk-windows
       6   0%               #<compiled 0x11111d71273e3f3a>
       3   0%             - #<compiled -0x18cecfa6e1ceea69>
       3   0%              - dired-get-filename
       3   0%                 dired-subdir-hidden-p
       3   0%             dired-remember-marks
       1   0%           - dired-insert-old-subdirs
       1   0%              dired-switches-recursive-p
```

How can I get to the root of this issue?

Comment: You should augment your question with the OS and its version that you are experiencing this on, the Emacs version and how you updated: distro package, build from source, something else?

Comment: In addition, which versions did you update from and to?  If you reinstall the old version, does the problem go away?  The profile indicates `[global-]auto-revert-mode`, so maybe you have something which is frequently modifying files in the background?  Do you have a *lot* of buffers?  I see magit appearing in your profiles, so perhaps Magit's auto-revert features are a trigger -- try disabling those if you can't see other causes for buffers to be auto-reverted.